# update a table but only non duplicate records

Tags: sql

table A

```
name, street, city, state, zip
bill, 123 main, newcity, null, 77777
bill, 123 main, newcity, null, 77777
fred, 23 west, greattown, null, 12345
bob, 4 a St, nowhere, null, 34567
```

table B

```
name, street, city, st, zip
bill, 123 main, newcity, me, 77777
bill, 123 main, newcity, me, 77777
fred, 23 west, greattown, ny, 12345
bob, 4 a St, nowhere, wy, 34567
```

i want to do

```
update table A
set state = tB.st
from 
table A tA inner join table B tB
on (tA.name = tB.name and tA.street = tB.street)
```

but I dont want to update the 2 records "bill, 123 main, newcity, null, 77777".

How do I exclude those rows from the tables?

Thanks
Charles

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Is there some id field on table A that makes the duplicate records distinct?

Comment: You could tack on something along the lines of "AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM A WHERE name = tB.name)" at the end of your UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+, you could do something like this:

```
;
WITH A_counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name, street, city, zip)
  FROM TableA
),   B_counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name, street, city, zip)
  FROM TableB
)
UPDATE A_counted
SET state = B.state
FROM B_counted B
WHERE A_counted.name   = B.name,
  AND A_counted.street = B.street,
  AND A_counted.city   = B.city,
  AND A_counted.zip    = B.zip
  AND A_counted.cnt    = 1
  AND B.cnt            = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is:

1) Create a temp table with the records in A that appear more than once.

2) Create a second temp table with all records in B that don't match records in the temp table from step 1.

3) Update all records from step 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to append 1 more conditional to your join:

```
update table A
set state = tB.st
from 
table A tA inner join table B tB
on (tA.name = tB.name and tA.street = tB.street and tA.name <> 'Bill')
```

This should exclude those two rows from even being seen by the update statement.